# Java formatted print map

Tags: java, text, formatting

I have a project where we need to print a formatted representation of the state of our simulation multiple times throughout the program. This formatting needs to be very specific but I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to go about setting up this print function.

The formatting needs to be exactly in the form of

[image: formatting]

the length of the 'x' and 'c' characters will be dynamic but at most 6 long.

Is there any framework or method I could use to set up this type of formatting?

Comment: Is there a reason a simple sysout won't do the trick?

Comment: To me because I dont know the length of the characters in the middle, I would have to check for each case to know exactly how to print them which could be different depending on the length.

Comment: Right.  And that's exactly what you need to do.  There are ways of efficiently checking information like that, but without any knowledge of your code, there's nothing anyone can do to help you.